# Strange Behavior of Truncate in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying the String#truncate method provided by Rails 3:

```
irb(main):001:0> "abcde".truncate(1)
=> "abc..."
irb(main):002:0> "abcde".truncate(2)
=> "abcd..."
irb(main):003:0> "abcde".truncate(3)
=> "..."
irb(main):004:0> "abcde".truncate(4)
=> "a..."
irb(main):005:0> "abcde".truncate(5)
=> "abcde"
irb(main):006:0> "abcde".truncate(6)
=> "abcde"
```

I am expecting something like `"a..."`, `"ab..."`, `"abc..."`...

I don't understand why it is acting like this.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length you provide to `truncate` should include the `...`, so lengths of 4 or greater should work perfectly.

There appears to be a bug in the `String#truncate` method. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb), it doesn't look like there's anything in there to handle supplied lengths less than 3.

Example:

When you supply `4` as the length, rails subtracts `3` for the `...`, leaving your adjusted length as `1`. So then rails uses that `1` as the ending part of a substring of "abcde":

```
"abcde"[0...1] + '...'
# => "a..."
```

However, if you supply `1` as the length, after subtracting the `3` your adjusted length becomes `-2`. Plugging `-2` into the range gives you this:

```
"abcde"[0...-2] + '...'
# => "abc..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the expected behaviour passing

```
:omission => ''
```

to truncate.

Comment: Does this work in 1.8.7? In 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2 your solution does not provide the output asked for.